# Create a systemd service for starting LAMP &c

Tags: systemd, services, lamp

I have a Linux-box with Ubuntu that I use for development.  I have disabled `Apache`, `MySQL` (well, MariaDB) and `PostgreSQL` (and a couple of other services), and would like to write a `systemd` service that I can use to start and stop these together on demand (when I want to test something).  Unfortunately `systemd` is totally Greek to me - I've tried to understand some tutorials, but it doesn't seems to be exactly what I need...

Not sure if it would be best making just a .service, or if a .target would be better (eg. a lamp.target)?

So is this possible?  How should I go about it?  Any good on-the-point examples or tutorials?

Comment: How did you disable the services? Was it a complete removal or are the three services you mentioned just set to not autostart at boot? 

Comment: @matigo No, just disabled them with systemctl disable so they don't start at boot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick little script that will do what you're asking:

```
#!/bin/bash

services=("apache2" "mysql" "postgresql")
action="start"
if [ {$1,,} == "stop" ]; then
        action="stop"
fi

# This script needs to be run with sudo, as it will be starting and or stopping
# services.

if ! [ $(id -u) = 0 ]; then
        echo "This script needs to be run with sudo." >&2
        exit 1
fi

# If we're here let's run through the list of services and start/stop them if
# their status does not meet the desired state.

for i in ${services[@]}
do
        sstat=$(systemctl is-active $i)
        if ([ {$sstat,,} == "active" ] && [ {$action,,} == "stop" ]); then
                echo "Stopping $i"
                sudo service $i $action
        fi

        if ([ {$sstat,,} == "inactive" ] && [ {$action,,} == "start" ]); then
                echo "Starting $i"
                sudo service $i $action
        fi
done
```

To use this:

1. Save the script to a file and give it a name that you'll remember, such as `lampp.sh`
2. Set the file as executable:

   ```
   chmod +x lampp.sh
   ```
3. Start (or stop) your LAMPP stack:

   ```
   sudo ./lampp.sh start
   ```

**Notes:**

1. This script currently works with `apache2`, `mysql` and `postgresql`, however, because you've said "a couple of other services" in your question, the script can be easily expanded to include the other services that you spin up or down with the LAMPP stack. Simply add them to the `services` array near the top of the file, and those other services will be included.
2. Services are started/stopped in the order they appear in the array. This *should* be fine as is but, if you have services that have dependencies, you may want to look at having the array reversed when issuing a `stop` command
3. By default, the script will start services. To stop services, use this command:

   ```
   sudo ./lampp.sh stop
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** capitalization is unimportant here, as the variable is converted to lower-case in the script when being compared.</sup>
4. This script supports *only* `start` and `stop`. Supplying any other value, even if it's a valid `systemd` command, will be treated as `start`
5. This script will check to see if the service is already in the desired state before issuing a command to start/stop the service
6. This script must be run with `sudo`, as it will be starting and stopping services